# iOS5, StoryBoards, ARC: Weird categories issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, categories

I've created a file with sql methods and now this file is really large. I'd like to split it for best practice and implementation simplicity. So, categories.

I've created in xCode new objective-c categories file -> DBAccess+Generals.h (.m).

.h:

```
#import "DBAccess.h"

@interface DBAccess (Generals)

-(void)newMeth;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "DBAccess+Generals.h"
#import "DBAccess.h"

@implementation DBAccess (Generals)

-(void)newMeth
{
  NSLog(@"New Meth");
}

@end
```

In DBAccess.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "DBAccess+Generals.h"



@interface DBAccess : NSObject
{
   NSString *databaseName;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *databaseName;
```

DBAccess.m

```
#import "DBAccess.h"
#import "DBAccess+Generals.h"

@implementation DBAccess
@synthesize databaseName;
sqlite3* database=nil;

-(id)init
{
  if ((self=[super init])) 
  {
    //[self initializeDataBase];
    databaseName=@"world_coins.db";
    //firstVerDB=@"ac_ch_ver.1.0.db";

  }
  return self;
}

//Tones of methods

@end
```

Looks like the code is OK. Getting error "interface implementation not found for DBAccess". I've googled and stackoverflowed around, but the issues described, are not my case.

any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In DBAccess.m you need @implementation DBAccess to define the actual implementation.

Comment: Is that an error at compile time, linker time, or runtime?

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan compile time.

Comment: @Brian Walker I have implementation in DBAccess. It's working class.

Comment: @Nathan: Show us that implementation please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the cyclic import

- `#import "DBAccess+Generals.h"` in *DBAccess.h*
- `#import "DBAccess.h"` in *DBAccess+Generals.h*

If you remove the first one, the code compiles.