# iOS: Trying to call method implemented in category

Tags: objective-c, ios, categories

The prequel for this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145981/ios5-storyboards-arc-weird-categories-issue).

I have a class (A) and the class has category. In the category I've defined and implemented a method.

Now I am trying in (let's assume B) class to call [a someMethod]. My B class can't reach this method. Isn't possible to call the category meths from some other class?

Comment: Categories are supposed to act as extensions to classes. They are kind of similar to subclassing. But categories written for a particular class can only be invoked by that class objects and not some other classes. For ex: If I write a category for NSString, I can only invoke it using an NSString object.

Comment: Category for DBAccess class. In other class: DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init]; [access myCategoryMeth]; Isn't the same case as NSString?

Comment: This is valid and it should work.

Comment: Show some sample code, please. Also explain what "can't reach" means. No syntax highlighting? Compiler warning? Runtime error?

Comment: Show you category declaration and implementation. Both .h and .m and show your #includes in class B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't show your code, but in the .m file that refers to the category method, you do need to import the header of the file that defines the category interface.

Comment: Not same result. It worked. Damn, I thought that #import DBAccess will be enough. Now I have to remember in which category my meth is implemented. It's another head arch.

Comment: you have to include the category

Answer (score 1):

If you define a category in a .m file, you will not be able to call the category's methods from outside of that .m file.

Comment: Ah. I was thinking of a class extension. Similar to category but it must act differently with importing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not provide enough information about your problem.  Thus, all we can do is tell you how it should be done, and guess about why you are having trouble.

When you post a question, you should post all the relevant information.  In this case, that would be the code that does not work.

Also, your statement

> My B class can't reach this method.

means almost nothing.  You get a compiler error, a runtime error, the syntax window does not show it, what exactly do you mean by that?

Now, when you implement a category on a class, you want to declare the category in a header (.h) file...

```
@interface Foo (BarExtensions)
- (NSString*)bar;
@end
```

and then, in the implementation (.m) file, provide the implementation for those methods.

```
@implementation Foo (BarExtensions)
- (NSString*)bar {
    return @"FooBar";
}
@end
```

Of course, you should name things appropriately.

Also, make sure you include the .m file in the list of files that get built for your target.

If you do that, there's not much left to go wrong.